# Como enviar ID de um objeto no autoComplete jQuery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, autocompletar

Preciso do ID do item selecionado no Autocomplete do jquery,ao selecionar o item pelo autocomplete , enviar ao formulario o ID do item selecionado. No label O texto ao enviar via post o ID do item

```
        public ActionResult Cadastrar()
    {
        var veiculoVM = new VeiculoViewModel();
        veiculoVM.Pessoas = PessoaRepositorio.ListarPessoas()
         .Select(p => new Pessoa() { Nome = p.Nome, Codigo = p.Codigo }).ToList();


    }

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Pessoas = new Array();

    @if (Model.Pessoas != null) {
        foreach (var item in Model.Pessoas) {
            @:Pessoas.push('@item'.replace("&#186;", " "));
        }
    }


    $('#Pessoa').autocomplete({
        lookup: Pessoas,
    });
})
```

```
   <fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("Cliente: ")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBox("Pessoa")
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CodigoPessoa, new { id = "hidden" })

    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("Categoria do Veículo: ")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(v => v.CodigoCategoriaVeiculo, Model.CategoriaVeiculoList)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("Descrição: ")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.Descricao, new { maxlength = "20" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("Ano de Fabricação: ")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.AnoFabricacao, new { maxlength = "4" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("Placa: ")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Placa, new { maxlength = "7" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label("Chassi: ")
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Chassi, new { maxlength = "20" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No seu autocomplete você terá muitos dados?

Comment: sim ! ele será uma lista de todas as pessoas que estao cadastradas em meu sistema

Answer (score 1):

No seu  `Controller` você pode retornar o `Codigo` e o `nome` em um  `Json` , deixando a sua consulta mais performática.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
public ActionResult Find( string term)
    {
        var resultado = PessoaRepositorio.METODO IENUMERABLE.Where(c => c.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()))
            .Select(c => new { value = c.Nome, id=c.Codigo });

        return Json(resultado.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

E em sua View, você teria o  `TextBox` do código (hidden) e o nome.

```
<div class="control-group">
                        @Html.Label("Cliente: ")
                        <div class="controls">
                             <input id="nomeCliente" type="text" class="form-control">
                             <input id="txtCodigo" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="CodigoPessoa"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

E faria a busca, utilizando o `AutoComplete`, junto com uma requisição `ajax` ficando assim:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#nomeCliente").autocomplete({
            //           source:  '@Url.Action("Find", "Funcionario")'
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "Find",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { 'term': request.term },
                        success: response
                    });
            },

            focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#CodigoPessoa").val(ui.item.value);
            },

            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#txtCodigo").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#txtCodigo").val(ui.item.id);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Onde no `script` ele faz uma busca no método `Find` do seu `Controller` retornando o `Nome` em seu `AutoComplete` e salvando o Codigo.

Comment: implementei mas nao esta dando certo a funcao, fica esse erro no console do navegador Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @HansMiller saberia em qual linha?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> o ero aponta para essa linha da pagina!